# Are there known counterexamples to Hennman's size principle for muscle unit recruitment?

Tags: muscles

It is known that generally muscle units are recruited from small to large, and that typically also means slow to fast twitch.  This principle is called [Hennman's size principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henneman%27s_size_principle).

I've seen many articles backing this claim up.  However, I'm curious if there are any known situations where this principle is known to fail.  (Perhaps when there is a known impulse arriving shortly and it needs to be opposed by large fast-twitch muscle).

All I have found so far are articles which agree with the principle, but it seems surprisingly simple for a biological system.